# Variance of random variable for normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, independence

How do I find the variance for

$z_n=\prod_{i=1}^n(1-k_i e^{a_i x})$

where $x$ is the random variable with a normal distribution and is the same for all $i$ (which is a subscript for time dependency which is not dependent with $x$).

I have tried using the method by [Goodman](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2282440?uid=3738744&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104093221011), but since I have same $x$ for all $i$'s, I don't know exactly how to proceed.

Comment: Since you aggregate over time $X$ cannot be the _same_ random variable -only $n$ _identically distributed_ random variables. In which case, the question arises: are they independent or not? The other possible case is to have "one draw" from a normal random variable at the first point in time, and then use this one draw as fixed value for all subsequent points in time. Which of the two cases is it?

Comment: What is the difference in both cases? Is it possible to derive the variance in both cases?

Comment: The difference is obvious: in the one case you have just one (log-normal) random variable, in the second case, many identically distributed random variables, that may or may be not independent. The issue is what holds in your case.

Comment: is it possible to derive the variance for one random variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, assume that there is one random variable, and that $n=2$.  Then

$$Z_2 = (1-k_1 e^{a_1 X})(1-k_2 e^{a_2 X}) = 1-k_2 e^{a_2 X}-k_1 e^{a_1 X}+k_1k_2 e^{(a_1+a_2) X}$$

And

$$Z_2^2 = (1-k_2 e^{a_2 X}-k_1 e^{a_1 X}+k_1k_2 e^{(a_1+a_2) X})(1-k_2 e^{a_2 X}-k_1 e^{a_1 X}+k_1k_2 e^{(a_1+a_2) X}) \\$$

$$\begin{align}& =1-k_2 e^{a_2 X}-k_1 e^{a_1 X}+k_1k_2 e^{(a_1+a_2) X} \\
&-k_2 e^{a_2 X}+k_2^2 e^{2a_2 X}+k_1k_2 e^{(a_1+a_2) X}-k_1k_2^2 e^{(a_1+2a_2) X}\\
&-k_1 e^{a_1 X}+k_1k_2 e^{(a_1+a_2) X}+k_1^2 e^{2a_1 X}-k_1^2k_2 e^{(2a_1+a_2) X}\\
&+k_1k_2 e^{(a_1+a_2) X}-k_1k_2^2 e^{(a_1+2a_2) X}-k_1^2k_2 e^{(2a_1+a_2) X} +k_1^2k_2^2 e^{(2a_1+2a_2) X}\end{align}  $$

$$ \begin{align}\Rightarrow Z_n^2 &= 1-2k_2 e^{a_2 X}-2k_1 e^{a_1 X}+k_2^2 e^{2a_2 X}+ k_1^2 e^{2a_1 X}\\
&+ 4k_1k_2 e^{(a_1+a_2) X} -2k_1^2k_2 e^{(2a_1+a_2) X}-2k_1k_2^2 e^{(a_1+2a_2) X}\\
&+k_1^2k_2^2 e^{(2a_1+2a_2) X} \end{align}$$

In general if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then  $b_iX=Y \sim N(b_i\mu, b_i^2\sigma^2)$

Also $W=e^{X}$ is a log-normal random variable, with $E(W)=e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2}$.

Finally $E(cW) = cE(W)$.

We see therefore that both $Z_2$ and $Z_2^2$ are just sums of scaled log-normal random variables, of which we want to calculate the expected value, nothing more. This won't change as $n$ increases, so

$$\text{Var}(Z_n) = E(Z_n^2) - [E(Z_n)]^2$$

will be computable as a matter of increasingly and exceedingly tedious arithmetic.

**ADDENDUM**
The above procedure will also work if we assume that there are many $X$'s, that are independent and jointly normal. In such a case, instead of, say, $(a_1+2a_2)X$ we will have $a_1X_1+2a_2X_2$ which will again be a normal random variable.